# How To Optimize This Complex MySql Query

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, mysqli, query-optimization

I have this query

`SELECT id, number, count, name FROM temp AS t1 WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM temp AS t2 
            WHERE t2.number = t1.number AND t2.count > t1.count
    ) = 0 AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp WHERE count < 3)`

Its currently taking too long to execute, table temp has 150 000 rows and increasing.

I am running this via php (mysqli). How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query the condition

`AND id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp WHERE count < 3)`

could be used as

```
and `count` < 3
```

You may also convert the subquery with `exists` strategy and finally adding some indexes.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

```
select id,number,`count`,name from temp t1
where t1.`count` < 3
and not exists(
 select 1 from temp t2 
 where t2.number = t1.number AND t2.count > t1.count 
)
```

The indexing may require if not already there as

```
alter table temp add index cnt_idx(`count`);
alter table temp add index number_idx(`number`);
```

Make sure to take a backup of the table before applying the index.

You can always use `explain select` to check the query health.